# Nano Receiver, another USB?

Tags: usb

I was wondering if there was a way to turn a nano receiver (used for wireless mouse and keyboard) into a mini USB or similar on Ubuntu.

Where is the nano receiver "mounted" on the computer, any idea? I tried `fdisk -l` but the device didn't seem to appear in the results as expected.

Comment: What's "mini USB or what ever"? Try again, less vaguely.

Comment: I've rolled this question back to it's original form as it was even less clear what the problem was after the first edit.

Answer (score 7):

After reviewing your [original post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/956816/revisions) it appears that you are operating under the misconception that your wireless transceiver contains storage like a flash drive. This is unlikely. Details on the device (including where it's mounted) can be had via `lsusb -v`